# Jquery is not loading in GitHub page, but is fine in CodePen

Tags: jquery

The jQuery code I am trying to execute is not working when rendered from GitHub. I have this code in a CodePen and it works fine.

I've tried to add the script at the bottom of the page in GitHub as I heard placing it in the head tag messes with parsing. I've added the `$(document).ready(function(){ });` in hopes that might have been the issue. I found out that lazy loading images is not supported through the usual libraries and added the proper one in.  I'm sure it is a simple fix but I can't find that answer.

This is posted just before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('h1').first().delay(100).animate({'opacity':'1'},600);
    $('i').last().delay(400).animate({'opacity':'1'},600);
    $('.gallery-row').delay(1000).animate({'opacity':'1'},1200);
    $(".item").lazyload({
       effect : "fadeIn"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can you check the network tab and see if your script is loading? also are there any console errors?

Comment: If possible could you also share a link to the GitHub page containing the error?

Comment: I just looked into how to check the console.  I'm not seeing any errors.  I also installed a javascript error detection extension for Chrome.  It's also not showing any errors.  My GitHub page is https://beerfolio.github.io/